# Apache 403 error (Forbidden) on windows

Tags: jquery, html, apache

I'm using Apache and send an ajax request using jQuery from `index.html`. The `get_data.pl` is a file on `cgi-bin`. I got `403 Forbidden error`. Anyone would help me and thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
    async : true,
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_data.pl"      
}).done(function(msg){
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
}).fail(function(xmlHttpRequest,statusText,errorThrown) {   
    console.log(JSON.stringify(xmlHttpRequest));
    console.log(statusText);
    console.log(errorThrown);       
});
```

What I got from the console:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE ...<title>403 Forbidden</title>...
<p>You don't have permission to access /get_data.pl\non this server.</p>\n</body>
</html>\n","status":403,"statusText":"Forbidden"}
```

It's Windows 7. I'm running with Chrome using administrator account.

After some time, I didn't find ways for the issue yet. I think I should provide more details for experts to reproduce my problem.
About my httpd.conf, I changed places based on the original one:
Line 193 in:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I delete the 2 lines:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Line 343 :

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
      AllowOverride None
      Options None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I changed this section to:

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
    Options  +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I placed the .pl file in cgi-bin folder, the index.html in htdocs folder.
I tried Windows7, Win2k3 64bit and WIn2k3 32bit. All have forbidden errors. I used Apache's default printenv.pl also.

Comment: Show your `.htaccess`.

Comment: I searched in conf folder but didn't find .htaccess. There's only htaccess.html under Apache2.2/manual folder and I don't think it's a config file you mentioned.

Comment: Are other requests to same directory (for example `/image.jpg`) also forbidden or it's just the `.pl` file?

Comment: I can run it from the command line: cgi-bin>get_data.pl

Comment: Do you have `mod_perl` installed?

Comment: Can't the URL `/cgi-bin/get_data.pl` be used? I think you are currently invocing `/get_data.pl`, and I can't see any Alias directives. Prefer absolute URLs wherever possible…

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing permissions to run `CGI` stuff and you can read about how to enable it  in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)

In short put something like this in your main config file(`https.conf`) :

```
<Directory /path/to/cgi-bin/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</Directory>
```

Hope it helps you forward.

**EDIT**
The problem was that the path used to access the script was incorrect. Log file showed `Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/get_data.pl"` while the `get_data.pl` file is not in `htdocs`, but in `cgi-bin` folder. Changing `url: "get_data.pl"` in the `ajax` call to locate the script in `cgi-bin` solved the problem.

Comment: No, I've done that. I have add:AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl in my httpd.conf and the path is Apache's default cgi-bin. Any way to trace the issue?

Comment: Importatnt you have `Options +ExecCGI` as well but I assume you have it. Check the error log file? Usually under `/var/log/apache2` but this could differ in your configuration.

Comment: Yes, the log file helps. I checked the log file shows:  "Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/get_data.pl" In fact, the get_data.pl file is not in htdocs folder, but in cgi-bin folder. When I called in the client script "url: "get_data.pl"", it defaults to htdocs folder, not cgi-bin folder. How can I do to assigned to it?

Comment: Add the path to your cgi-bin folder to the url in the script, or use [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to make a shorter URL and refer to that one.

Comment: I thought the cgi-bin is the default executing root which the Apache will found and needn't refer explicitly. I use the short name in the referring url and it's OK now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's working. `DocumentRoot` specify what is considered root directory for the host.